# Joining with different table stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure like this

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spCarCallFetch] @Carid nvarchar(20)
as
begin
  Select 
      k.tid, k.HBarcode, m.make, t.plateno ,v.vtype, l.locname,
      mdl.model, c.Colname 
  from 
      transaction_tbl t, KHanger_tbl k, make_tbl m, vtype_tbl v, Location_tbl l, Model_tbl mdl, Color_tbl C  
  where 
      t.tbarcode = @carid and t.mkid = m.mkid and v.vtid = t.vtid 
      and t.locid = l.locid and mdl.mdlid = t.mdlid and t.colid = c.colid 
      and t.transactID = k.transactID
end
```

While executing this

```
exec spCarCallFetch'51891044554'
```

Output:

```
tid         HBarcode   make plateno   vtype         locname        model       Colname--------------------------------------------
6           564       BMW   44554    Normal       Fashion Avenue  520          Red
```

here tid is taking from KeyHanger table, but correspond name of tid is saved in Terminal table, actually I want to fetch corresponding name of tid.

My tables look like this:

**KHanger_tbl**

```
transactid                              HBarcode                tid
--------------------------------------- ----------------------------------
19                                      34                      7
22                                      002                     5
21                                      1                       7
23                                      200005                   6
```

**Terminals_tbl**

```
tid         UniqueName
----------- --------------------------------------------------
5           Key Room-1
6           Podium -1
7           Key Room - 2
```

I want to take uniqueName of corresponding tid. How can I write a stored procedure for this? If anyone knows, please help me

Comment: This looks like SQL Server (you should always tag with the database you are using).  I would suggest a table-values function instead. It makes the join much easier.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just join the terminals table to the hangars table on the tid attribute and include uniguename in the select part?

Comment: ya am using sql server only,,i am beginner in stored procedur,,,so can u please show once how to write stored procedure for getting uniq name

Comment: from the transaction table i dont have any direct link to terminal table,,, first i have to take tid from KHanger_tbl then only i can take uniq name from terminal table

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: It is absolutely inconceivable that you use those implicit joins. A very bad havbit that you need to stop immediately. They are a SQL antipattern. They are far more likely to be incorrect and have accidnental corss joins, they create problems if you need to change a join to a left join or add a left join (which you cannot do using that syntax as the code to do that is deprecated and it was wrong even as far back as SQl Server 2000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

As suggested in a comment explicit joins are what should be used, and then the query should look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCarCallFetch] @Carid NVARCHAR(20)
AS

BEGIN

  SELECT
    k.tid, k.HBarcode, m.make,
    t.plateno, v.vtype, l.locname,
    mdl.model, c.Colname, te.UniqueName

  FROM transaction_tbl t

  INNER JOIN KHanger_tbl   AS k   ON t.transactID = k.transactID
  INNER JOIN make_tbl      AS m   ON t.mkid = m.mkid 
  INNER JOIN vtype_tbl     AS v   ON v.vtid = t.vtid 
  INNER JOIN Location_tbl  AS l   ON t.locid = l.locid 
  INNER JOIN Model_tbl     AS mdl ON mdl.mdlid = t.mdlid 
  INNER JOIN Color_tbl     AS c   ON t.colid = c.colid 
  INNER JOIN Terminals_tbl AS te  ON k.tid = te.tid

  WHERE t.tbarcode = @carid 

END
```

Comment: It is a SQL antipattern to use implicit joins, you should not be condoning their use in your answer.

Comment: You're right. I updated the query with explict joins instead now.